# Image not displaying in web view of snack.expo.io?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using snack.expo.io for React Native development.  In my render() method, I'm including an Image reference like this:

```
return (
  <View>
      <Image source={require('./assets/my-image.png')} />
  </View>
);
```

The image displays as expected in the "Android" and "iOS" preview tabs but nothing is displayed in the "Web" preview tab.  Any idea what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 2):

I created expo snack example with image:
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/image-demo

You have to define style for Image in the web version.